# CoronaSDK - clip the listview using tableview library

Tags: coronasdk

I have a navbar at the top of a screen with a listview.  The problem is that, even in the sample code for the listview samples, you can click on the navbar, and the capture phase will not end at the navbar, but instead continues all the way to the listview.  This makes it so that, as soon as you scroll the list underneath the navbar, any click on the navbar captures the click on the list item instead of on the navbar buttons.  I've tried to add the navbar group back to the maingroup on the handler, but that doesn't seem to work (visually, it's still on top, anyway).  I also tried returning true when the navbar button was clicked to end the capture phase, but that didn't work, either.

I want to be able to go from one listview to another (drill-down type), but that's a problem right now as you can't scroll the list and then access the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was close to the answer the first time, but misstepped just enough to throw myself off.  The key is to put the "return true" statement during the "began" phase.  That did the trick.